# Find and compare lengths of individual words in a string

Tags: java

So I need to write a program that reads a sentence of five words, and finds the longest word in the sentence and displays it.  If there happen to be two equally large words, it just displays the first largest word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Longest_Word {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line;
        String q, w, e, r, t;

        System.out.print("Enter a five word sentence: ");
        line = in.nextLine();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);

        q = scanner.next();
        w = scanner.next();
        e = scanner.next();
        r = scanner.next();
        t = scanner.next();

        System.out.println(q + " " + r);
    }
}
```

You can probably tell where I'm stuck.  I really don't know how to compare these words.  The first thing that came to mind was to use if/else to compare them individually, using line.length().

Can't use array, .split, or loops (sadly).

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't wait to compare them all at the end..... ;-)

Comment: I find it incomprehensible why you cannot use arrays, .split or loops. Is it for some computer science homework? Because in the real world one would simply loop over the 5 String variables to determine the longest.

Comment: @Jireugi but there is no need for such things...which is probably part of the lesson...what it if was 100 million words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if/else and loops are the same for this problem.

```
String largerString = q;
if(w.length()>largerString.length())
{
    largerString = w;
}
if(e.length()>largerString.length())
{
    largerString = e;
}
if(r.length()>largerString.length())
{
    largerString = r;
}
if(t.length()>largerString.length())
{
    largerString = t;
}
System.out.println(largerString);
```

Comment: This and Jireugi's answer helped a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: @Conf3tti great! Then if you don´t mind you could mark one of the answers as being correct.

Answer (score 1):

Show your teacher this!

```
Stream.generate(scanner::next).limit(5)
    .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the largest word, you can do it as follows, and it will be dynamic too in case the number of words is more than 5.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String line;
String q, w, e, r, t;

System.out.println("Enter a five word sentence: ");
line = in.nextLine();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);

String maxWord = "";
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String word =scanner.next();
    if(word.length()>maxWord.length())
        maxWord = word;
}
System.out.println(maxWord);
```

Comment: The question states no loops.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints I suggest you use if statements as you assumed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Longest_Word {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String line;
    String q, w, e, r, t;

    System.out.print("Enter a five word sentence: ");
    line = in.nextLine();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);

    q = scanner.next();
    String longest = q;

    w = scanner.next();
    if (w.length()>longest.length())
        longest = w;

    e = scanner.next();
    if (e.length()>longest.length())
        longest = e;

    r = scanner.next();
    if (r.length()>longest.length())
        longest = r;

    t = scanner.next();
    if (t.length()>longest.length())
        longest = t;

    System.out.println(longest);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all the values in list and use Java Streams to find longest String

```
String logestStr = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(String::length)).get();
```

Comment: Your could shorten that comparator. `Comparator.comparing(String::length)`